# How to hide a value for each item in a <asp:dropdownlist>

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `<asp:DropDownList>` element filled with items, where each item represents an application name.  I would like to pass a hidden value (the url of the application be specific) for each of these items. I need the value in my Javascript code. I think my code would look better if I prevent the operation of having to query the database using an ajax call.

Is it possible to hide multiple values for each item in a dropdownlist? If so, how?

Comment: You can set some delimiter separated string as item value, and with javascript , get the changed value, split that value and use whichever you need.

Comment: @ArindamNayak Yes, that's one way :) I was hoping .NET had some trick for situations like these.

Comment: As far as i know, you have to do it like this, or wait till more answers/comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codebehind:

1. Use the Newtonsoft.Json library to convert data into a JSON object
   https://dotnetfiddle.net/tMXHsI
2. Set an `<asp:HiddenField>` value with that content.

On the page, in javascript:

1. Parse the hidden field's value `var myURLs = JSON.parse( HiddenField.value );`

You now have a javascript object that you can pull data from.